Convergence Interval for the Newton-Raphson Method
Let $ f(x) = 7 - \frac{1}{x} $ for $ x > 0 $.
I am using the Newton-Raphson method:
$$
x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}
$$
to find the root $\frac{1}{7}$. This part is straightforward.
However, I am curious: How far from $\frac{1}{7}$ can the initial guess be such that the Newton-Raphson method still converges to the root $\frac{1}{7}$? Specifically, how can I calculate the "maximum convergence interval" for the Newton-Raphson method for this function?
From my experiments, it seems that the largest convergence interval is the largest closed interval contained within $ (0, \frac{2}{7})$. However, I cannot determine why this interval arises or how to derive it analytically.
Is there an analytical method to determine the maximum convergence interval?

Plugging your $f$ into the formula and simplifying gives $x_n = x_{n-1}(2-7x_{n-1})$. If we start with a value outside the interval (0,2/7), the result is negative. Plugging that negative value in for the next iteration will give another negative, and so on. Since the root is positive this can't possibly converge to the root. Thus we have a bound on the interval of convergence. As for why the interior of (0,2/7) leads to convergence (if it indeed does), I'm not sure. I haven't done much numerical analysis in a while.

The method diverges if it reaches a point, derivate at which is very small. Then the iterative update will start to contribute to exponential divergence towards extreme negative values. To me it seems like the boundaries of the convergence interval should be defined by the largest/smallest possible values, for which the first update iteration doesn't result in large enough positive or (any) negative value

To expand on @jdg1729's comment -- given $x_n$, $x_{n+1}$ will be wherever the tangent line to $f$ crosses the $x-$axis. Since $f$ is concave down, increasing, and positive, for all $1/7<x<2/7$ the tangent line will cross the $x-$axis to between $0$ and the root at $1/7$. Each of these tangents will then cross closer to $1/7$ than the previous iterate.  In general, of course, it is quite difficult (fun?) to determine the largest interval (or set of intervals) for which Newton converges to a particular root for a given function.

By Darboux theorem,  since the second derivative is always negative, you should not have any problem if $f(x_0)<0$. This does restrict a lot

This analysis is particular to the specific $f$.
$f$ is strictly increasing on $x>0$. Since $f'' < 0$ we see that $f$ ss concave and so $f'$ is non increasing. Also note that $f'>0$. Let $x^*={1 \over 7}$ be the unique zero.
The update equation is given by $f(x_n) + f(x_n)' (x_{n+1}-x_n)  = 0$, hence if $f(x_n)<0$ then $x_{n+1} >x_n$ and if $f(x_n)>0$ then $x_{n+1}<x_n$.
Suppose $x_n \in (0,x^*)$, then $f(x_{n+1}) = f(x_n)+f'(\xi_n)(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ for some $\xi_n \in [x_n,x_{n+1}]$. Then
$f(x_{n+1}) \le f(x_n) + f(x_n)' (x_{n+1}-x_n)  = 0$ and so $x_{n+1} \in [x_n,x^*]$.
Hence if any $x_n \in (0, x^*)$ then $x_n \le x_{n+1} \le x^*$ and it is straightforward to see that $x_n \to x^*$.
If $x_n \in (x^*,\infty)$ then in order for the iteration to be defined, the update should produce a point in $(0, \infty)$. In particular, we need $x_n-{f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)} = x_n(2-7x_n)>0$, that is $x_n \in (x^*, {2 \over 7})$.
Suppose $x_n \in (x^*, {2 \over 7})$, then $f(x_{n+1}) = f(x_n)+f'(\xi_n)(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ for some $\xi_n \in [x_{n+1}, x_n]$. Then $f(x_{n+1}) \le 
 f(x_n) + f(x_n)' (x_{n+1}-x_n)  = 0$ and so $x_{n+1} \in [x_n,x^*]$ and the previous analysis applies.
Hence if $x_0 \in (0, {2 \over 7})$ the sequence converges to $x^*$, otherwise either $f$ is not defined at $x_0$ or $x_1$.

This is a example of a reoccurring problem, i.e., given a nonlinear function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with a zero $z \in I$, find the largest subinterval $J \subseteq I$ such that $z \in J$ and, say, Newton's method is defined and converges to $z$ for all $x_0 \in J$. We shall handle the specific case using a technique that is fairly general.
Let $\alpha > 0$ be given and consider the problem of computing the reciprocal value $\alpha^{-1}$ using Newton's method. Let $f$ denote the function given by $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \alpha$$ and let $g$ denote the function that defines a Newton step, i.e., $$g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x + x(1-\alpha x).$$
Using long division, we find that
$$ g(x) - \alpha^{-1} = (1 - \alpha x)(x - \alpha^{-1}).$$
We conclude that the error will be reduced in the sense that
$$ |g(x) - \alpha^{-1}| < |x - \alpha^{-1}|$$
if and only if
$$ | 1 - \alpha x | < 1.$$
Equivalently,
$$ -1 < 1 - \alpha x < 1$$
or
$$ x \in (0, 2 \alpha^{-1}).$$
It follows that Newton's method for this $f$ converges to the reciprocal value $\alpha^{-1}$ if the initial guess has a relative error that is less than $L < 1$. This is a very modest requirement.
Under modest conditions on $f$, we can find a function $C = C(z)$ such that $$g(x) - z = C(x)(x-z).$$
We see that the error will reduced in absolute value if and only if $$|C(x)| < 1.$$ There is a formula for $C$, but it is a bit tedious and for some examples it is faster to compute $C$ by dividing $g(x)-z$ by $x-z$. We then seek the largest interval $J$ containing $z$ such that $|C(x)| \leq L <1$ for all $x \in J$. We would be remiss if we did not emphasize that our concept of convergence is very practical, i.e., strict reduction of the absolute value of the error, but also a bit stronger than the standard concept of convergence.
